# How do I configure the clipping region when drawing with XNA's SpriteBatch?

Tags: xna, spritebatch

I have a `SpriteBatch` that is set to draw to a `RenderTarget2D` that is 500 pixels larger in both height and width. Whenever I draw to a point outside of the physical screen dimensions, it will not draw the object.

I am performing some 3D transforms on the texture so I need the areas outside the screen to be drawn. I have tried setting culling to `None` and this had no effect.

Comment: Some code, please?

Comment: If you're talking about the `CullMode`, that is the winding order of the polygons - it's not relevant.

Comment: This question was cross-posted to Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060033/xna-spritebatch-drawing-off-screen

Comment: If your world/view/projection transforms put the entire sprite outside of the view frustum, it will get culled no matter what you do.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is the Viewport is not large enough. Its supposed to default to the size of the current RenderTarget2D but check to make sure that it is.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `Viewport` on your `GraphicsDevice` before drawing to your `RenderTarget2D`.

```
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(myRenderTarget2D);
GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width += 500; //or a more sensible calculation
GraphicsDevice.ViewPort.Height += 500;
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);
//Spritebatch operations
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.viewport

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport_members